# Follow redirects in AbstractPrimePageTest

Tags: selenium, primefaces

I am currently working my way into the new native support for Selenium in Primefaces. I wrote my first very basic test case. Basically, I want to fill in a login form and submit it. Usually when I press the login button, the web browser is redirected to the index page of the application. The web browser instantiated by Primefaces however, doesn't follow the redirect but stays on the login page. Do you have any idea why this might be the case? And how to change this behavior?

My page object:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.FindBy;
import org.primefaces.selenium.AbstractPrimePage;
import org.primefaces.selenium.component.CommandButton;
import org.primefaces.selenium.component.InputText;
import org.primefaces.selenium.component.Password;

public class LoginPage extends AbstractPrimePage {

    @FindBy(id= "username")
    private InputText usernameField;
    @FindBy(id="password")
    private Password passwordField;
    @FindBy(id="loginButton")
    private CommandButton submit;

    @Override
    public String getLocation() {
        return "login.xhtml";
    }

    public InputText getUsernameField() {
        return usernameField;
    }

    public Password getPasswordField() {
        return passwordField;
    }

    public CommandButton getSubmit() {
        return submit;
    }
}
```

My test case:

```
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.primefaces.selenium.AbstractPrimePageTest;

public class PrimefacesLoginTest extends AbstractPrimePageTest {

    @Test
    public void loginTest(LoginPage loginPage) {
        assertIsAt(loginPage.getLocation());
        assertDisplayed(loginPage.getUsernameField());
        assertDisplayed(loginPage.getPasswordField());
        assertDisplayed(loginPage.getSubmit());
        assertEnabled(loginPage.getSubmit());
        loginPage.getUsernameField().sendKeys("username");
        loginPage.getPasswordField().sendKeys("password");
        loginPage.getSubmit().submit();
        Assertions.assertFalse(loginPage.isAt());
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance for any answers!

Comment: Try to check the network tab, maybe a JS error occured, too. There is nothing in Selenium or PrimeSelenium which should prevent redirects.

Comment: I found the answer: It was a version conflict within our app.